# Solve equations involving summation expressions in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, fitting, vector-calculus

I am trying to solve the simple linear regression equation analytically in Mathematica (not using builtin functions). I managed to calculate the gradient as follows f is loss function using RSS and weights w0 and w1:

```
f[w0_, w1_] := Sum[(Subscript[y, i] - (w0 + w1*Subscript[x, i]))^2, {i, 0, n}]
Grad[f[w0, w1], {w0, w1}]
```

The solution is correctly output as

```
{Sum[-2*(-w0 - w1*Subscript[x, i] + Subscript[y, i]), {i, 0, n}], 
  Sum[-2*Subscript[x, i]*(-w0 - w1*Subscript[x, i] + Subscript[y, i]), 
   {i, 0, n}]}
```

Now how to solve the case where I need to set the Gradient of vectors equals 0 to get the analytic solutions for w0 and w1. The analytic solution to the equation is (N=n)

```
w1 = (Sum[Subscript[x, i]*Subscript[y, i], {i, 0, n}] - 
    Sum[Subscript[x, i]*Sum[Subscript[y, i]/N, {i, 0, n}], {i, 0, n}])/
   (Sum[Subscript[x, i]^2, {i, 0, n}] - 
    Sum[Subscript[x, i]*Sum[Subscript[x, i]/N, {i, 0, n}], {i, 0, n}])
```

and for w0 is

```
w0 = (Sum[Subscript[y, i], {i, 0, n}] - w1*Sum[Subscript[x, i], {i, 0, n}])/N
```

I tried Solve to solve this system of equations but without any success. Can you kindly help me to do this in Mathematica or is it not possible

Comment: which variable you want to solve it for?

Comment: w0 and w1. I want to get the weights analytically. the answers fro w0 and w1 are the actual solutions

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site and repost your code in text-only form. As it is, your code is entirely unreadable.